# Extract property field from database Odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo

If you watch some tables in Odoo database (like res_partner), you notice that some fields are not displayed (like property_payment_term_id).
This is because some fields are property fields and they appear in the ir_property table.
But how can I extract a property field value (for example, extract property_payment_term_id)?

some references:
https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#property-fields

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/explain-fields-property-24622

Comment: Hey @Hydronit, could you clarify what you mean by *extract*? Are you trying to select property values via an SQL query?

Comment: Yes, perfect. I'm tring to extract data with a ODBC connection using phpPaAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could help:

```sql
SELECT p.*, substring(ip.value_reference from 22) :: Integer AS property_payment_term_id
  FROM res_partner AS p
       LEFT JOIN ir_property AS ip
       ON ip.name = 'property_payment_term'
          AND ip.res_id = CONCAT('res.partner,', p.id);
```

Comment: I tried with the following code, but it returns only NULL value in payment_term_id   :


SELECT res_partner.name, ir_property.value_reference :: Integer AS payment_term_id
  FROM res_partner
     LEFT JOIN ir_property
       ON ir_property.name = 'property_payment_term'